# Resolve routes by named parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

I have ASP Core 2.2 app. I defined controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Web.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult GetById(int id)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

When I request with url `/api/users/3` everything works fine, method `GetById` is called. But if I try to request `/api/users?id=3` method `Get` is called and I don't know how to fix that. Moreover I would like to create two similar method different only by parameter name. For example `public IActionResult GetById(int id)` and `public IActionResult GetByAge(int age)` so I need strict routing by named parameters if possible. I don't want to implement custom middleware to resolve routes myself I wanna try to find ASP feature for that.

Answer (score 0):

The url `/api/users/3` :  "3" is used as part of the route value .

The url `/api/users?id=3`: "3" is used as a query string in the url .

Attribute routing with `Http[Verb]` attributes is the value of which is part of the route value

You could change the Route attribute above the controller to specify action name like below :

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    // Get api/users/get
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    //Get api/users/GetById/3
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult GetById(int id)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Reference :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ok, I understood about attribute routing but I'm interested could I resolve requests by named parameters?